# how to minimize latency with usb 2

Tags: c++, windows-10, usb, low-latency

I'm writing a simulator for XCP - an automotive protocol - on the PC.

I'm using a USB-to-CAN device and C++.

The issue with implementing this on PC, as opposed to on embedded hardware, is that XCP has very tight timeout message-reply requirements; it can be as low as `100us`.

The actual code that would be running on the PC is trivial because it would merely return dummy data.

**QUESTION**

Given my requirement for `100us` response time, is it even possible to achieve on PC running Windows 10 **consistently**?

Answer (score 2):

No.

Task scheduler resolution in userspace on a PC is in the order of milliseconds, not microseconds, so even just context switching blows your budget out of the water.

There is no way you can guarantee real-time execution in such an operating system, except possibly by writing a kernel driver (though whether that's even true is beyond my expertise).

You really need to be doing something like this in hardware or firmware.